# How to open multiple file trees in IDEA (WebStorm)

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Goal: View multiple scopes(file tree) at once.

I'm modifying a little old web node application, the view folder and logic handling are written in different places, but I need to see each other.

So, I would like to have multiple file trees in the same project for easy navigation.

However, since the folders are so far apart from each other, I set up a scope and try to switch between them each time.

Sorry, my English is not very good, so I use a little translation. I'm attaching a picture just in case.

Thank you.

[image: Explanation image]

Comment: It's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a few solutions.
It is the Favorites window.
Maybe the scope is not available, but I was able to increase the number of project views to two.

I can't open more than three of them, so if there is a convenient way to do this, please let me know.

Thank you.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh2qz.png)